How to execute cubit function from a void function of a class in Flutter
how you are calling a cubit function from a void function of stateless/ful widget. I assume in an ideal world all functions should be placed in cubits but similar to context.read<MyCubit>().myfunction(); which i can use in onpressed of a Button Widget i need a way to execute the cubit function from a void function. Is that possible?

To call a Cubit function from a void function in Flutter Pass BuildContext to your function
void _onPressed(BuildContext context) {
  context.read<MyCubit>().myFunction();
}

Call the function when needed, like in an onPressed event:
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () => _onPressed(context),
  child: Text('Call Cubit'),
)


Thanks for your suggestion, but it is not worked out for me. I can not provide context, because the void is for my AppLifecycleListener. My listener looks like this AppLifecycleListener(       onStateChange: _handleStateChange,     ).  In side the _handleStateChange which looks like this void _handleStateChange(AppLifecycleState state) async {     setState(() {       _state = state;     });     if (_state!.name == 'paused') {       settings.appstatus = 'paused';       context.read<PlayerEnergyCubit>().stoptimer();}}. So passing BuildContext not work.

One thing you can try is use flutter_fgbg: ^0.6.0 package to listen app state and update your state according to it
